# Loop. Unhide 2 rows for each row showing in another sheet

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have a spreadsheet (Sheet3) which collects and sorts data from 25 other sheets.  So I don't have a ton of empty rows in Sheet3 I do a VBA loop that first checks to see if a sheet is visible, then it hides and unhides rows based on whether or not they are hidden in the 25 other sheets, like so:

```
Sheet3.Rows("1791:9290").EntireRow.Hidden = True
For i = 1205 To 1354
    If Sheet1.Visible = True Then
        If Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Sheet3.Rows(i + 586).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

    If Sheet2.Visible = True Then
        If Sheet2.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Sheet3.Rows(i + 886).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

    If Sheet4.Visible = True Then
        If Sheet4.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Sheet3.Rows(i + 1186).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

    etc...
```

Due to the type of data I need to pull I unfortunately can't match sheet 3 up with the other 25 sheets row for row.  For each row visible in the other 25 sheets, I need Sheet3 to **unhide 2 rows**.

For example, if SheetX Row 1 is visible, Sheet3 must make rows 1 and 2 visible.  If SheetX Row 2 is visible, Sheet 3 must make rows 3 and 4 visible, and so on.

Is there any way to do this outside of me having to change all of the 25 other sheets to double their row count?  This is only one part of a huge project and I'd prefer not to add a few thousand more rows if it can be avoided.

Comment: If you use a range containing 2 rows in your `...EntireRow.Hidden = False` statement, you can unhide 2 rows at a time. As for selecting the rows to be unhidden, you could use a fairly simple arithmetic formula like `Sheet2.Range("A" & 2 * i + 586 & ":" & "A" & 2 * i + 587).EntireRow.Hidden = False`.

Comment: The problem with your suggestion (and this is the main issue here) is that even unhiding two rows will only work on the first step of the loop.  If I tell it to unhide two rows each time then you'll get this: Loop 1- Unhides Rows 1 and 2; Loop 2- Unhides Rows 2 and 3; Loop 3- Unhides Rows 3 and 4.  I need it like this:  Loop 1- Unhides Rows 1 and 2; Loop 2- Unhides Rows 3 and 4; Loop 3- Unhides Rows 5 and 6

Comment: Idk if this even improves the code at all.  But as a side point, you can rewrite the inner `if` statements to instead use boolean logic: `Sheet3.Rows(i + 586).EntireRow.Hidden = (Sheet3.Rows(i + 586).EntireRow.Hidden And Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the only way to do this was to add another integer that would change each time through the loop.  So I added `Dim J As Integer` and set `j = 0`. I added a line to unhide two rows through each loop and incorporated `j` into that code.  Then I added `j = j + 1` to the end of the loop.

So here's how it looks:

```
Dim j As Integer
j = 0        

Sheet3.Rows("1791:9290").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        For i = 1205 To 1354
            If Sheet1.Visible = True Then
                If Sheet1.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                    Sheet3.Rows(i + j + 586).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Sheet3.Rows(i + j + 587).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            End If

            If Sheet2.Visible = True Then
                If Sheet2.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                    Sheet3.Rows(i + j + 886).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Sheet3.Rows(i + j + 887).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            End If

            If Sheet4.Visible = True Then
                If Sheet4.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                    Sheet3.Rows(i + j + 1186).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Sheet3.Rows(i + j + 1187).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                End If
            End If

    etc...

        j = j + 1
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Cells` and resize to 2 rows in height before applying `.EntireRow`.

```
Sheet3.Cells(i + 586, 1).Resize(2, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

The [Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) will adjust the height of the range being referenced. The subsequent [Range.EntireRow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836.aspx) continues the change in cell reference to include the entire row.

Comment: Hi Jeeped. This causes the same issue I referenced in the comment that I provided up above.  This only works correctly the first time through the loop.  When I need rows 3 and 4, it gives me rows 2 and 3. When I need rows 5 and 6, it gives me rows 3 and 4.  I need 7 and 8, and it gives me 4 and 5.  I need a way to increase i as it pertains to Sheet3 by one count each time through the loop.